# Cubic root formula derivation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

I'm trying to understand the derivation for the cubic root formula. The text I am studying from describes the following steps:

$$x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$

Reduce this to a depressed form by substituting $y = x + \frac{a}{3}$. Such that:

$$y^3 = (x + \frac{a}{3})^3 = x^3 + ax^2 + \frac{a^2}{3}x + \frac{a^3}{27}$$

So the cubic equation becomes $y^3 + b'y + c'=0$, which can then be written as $y^3 + 3hy + k = 0$.

I understand that the aim is to remove the quadratic component, but where $b'$ and $c'$ are used I obviously lack some elementary knowledge. I feel like adding $b'y$ and $c'$ to $y^3$ modifies the last two terms, meaning they equate to $bx + c$, is that correct?

I don't understand why $3h$ is chosen though, can anyone clarify?

Comment: A very good walkthrough:
http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/12/abel-and-the-insolvability-of-the-quintic-part-1.html

Comment: From the discussion **orion** links to (and similar ones), perhaps it makes it clearer that the choice of $ \ 3h \ $ makes that term look like one in a binomial expansion. The analogous derivation for the quartic equation has $ \ 4h \ . $  (Unfortunately -- which left people scratching their heads for a couple centuries -- this trick doesn't work when you move on to the _quintic_...)

Comment: Thanks, really useful guide. So the 3h essentially cancels out the 1/3, makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace $x$ in your original equation by $y-\frac{a}{3}$, you get:

- $y^3+p\cdot y+q$

with

- $p=b-\frac{a^2}{3}$
- $q=\large\frac{2a^3}{27}\normalsize -\large\frac{ab}{3}\normalsize +c$

And for what? Now you are able to solve the new problem without a quadratic component by [Cadano's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) (bether: del Ferro-"Tartaglia"-Cardano method).

Comment: ...which ought to be called the del Ferro-"Tartaglia"-Cardano method, since there were contributions to various degrees from each of them.  What I find remarkable about this work (and Ferrari's solution of the quartic equation) is that it was done _before_ the introduction of the symbolic algebraic notation we've used since Viete and Descartes.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: that's true.. very crazy - therefore an up-vote! :)

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.